# Combine Two Custom Taxonomy Terms in URL WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm new to WordPress development.

I have been working on a project that requires, combining two custom taxonomies to make a better URL for SEO purposes.

These are two custom taxonomies:

1. Location
2. Brand

I was given to make a URL like: https://demosite.com/brand/c/location

This will show the specific brand for a specific location.

For example https://demosite.com/apple/india

This will show the brands(apple) from India.

Now I'm struggling to find how can I generate such URL combinations automatically for all the brands and locations. And all such URLs should be available in the sitemap as well. The other challenge I have is to use the custom template for this URL format.

Comment: What if anything have your tried?

Comment: I have applied rewrite rules for location and brand, but somehow I didn't work? Also, I need to load the custom template if both taxonomy present in URL